# Installing a new Laravel source on localhost laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am new at laravel (just installed laravel!).

I have searched many websites and tested any solution I found but none of them works for me. I have installed laravel in my localhost (Ex: localhost/laravel);

I have a laravel website source that contains files & folders in below:
floders:
-admin
-assets
-components
-dist
-src
files:
- .htaccess
- 404.php
- etc etc ...
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- and other php files

in some solutions they says that I must run two simple code:
composer install
php artisan:migrate

but I have no idea where and how to do that when I haven't any composer file in my source. I tested package.json install but it shows me errors.

I need help about this project. it is not in laravel directory just another directory in www folder like (localhost/test).
What should I do to import this source to laravel and run it?

**UPDATE 1**

After searching in Laravel Docs I found this line of code:

```
composer require laravel/homestead --dev
```

But when I run this on my project directory I see this error:

```
    [InvalidArgumentException]
      Could not find a matching version of package laravel/triplee. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: It seems you are not following the right way to install Laravel. Please read this simple documentation thoroughly and install `composer`, then Laravel Framework.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#installing-laravel.

Comment: I already installed Laravel Framework and it runs in localhost/laravel directory of my pc. I just downloaded a laravel project source from gitlab and there is no composer file on it only package.json. so what is first step?

Comment: Can you share the GitLab link if possible..?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new at laravel, I suggest you to use [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) for this. You can find lots of videos about installation of laravel with vagrant: 
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=laravel+vagrant

Besides it's comfortable usage, it also provides great advantages.